# Pipes thawed, cold water runs, not hot water

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, pipe, bathroom-fixtures

Our pipes froze recently and we heated the ones connected to the outside of the house. They thawed and the cold water is running now. However, I cannot get the hot water to run, or my tub faucet either. the heat is on in the house, and the water heater is located in the bathroom closet. We have pex piping running in the bathroom and all piping from the water heater is located inside interior walls. Is there something I can do? Or am I missing something.

Comment: What about the supply to the waterheater it may still be frozen. Pipe insulation and possibly heat tape may be needed if it regularly gets cold enough to freeze solid, heating pipes can be dangerous. I had to repair a section of pipe that exploded because the owner was using a propane torch and boiled the water between solid ice plugged pipe he was in the hospital for fragments and steam burns when his wife called to get the plumbing repaired. Use caution when trying to thaw pipes this was my only direct contact with this kind of accident but I have heard of others.